# What ruby testing library uses (or has used) the class-level syntax `expect {}`?

Tags: ruby, testing, shoulda

I'm refurbishing some old tests, which appear to be Test::Unit with Shoulda.  Some parts have a syntax `expect {block}`, but I can't find any references to expect in the current Shoulda code.  `expect` appears at the class level, where I see other `setup` or `should` statements.

Comment: Sounds like `rspec` to me. http://rspec.info

Comment: Except that in rspec, `expect` is used inside `it`.  Here, the `expect` is used in the same way as `it {}`

Comment: When you are talking about *old*, which time in the past do you mean?

Comment: All the expects seem to be from the second half of 2009

Comment: if the test works try slapping in a 
```puts method(:expect).source_location```
and that will show you where it's defined
i.e
```puts method(:ap).source_location #=> ["lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/core_ext/kernel.rb", 19]```